# The no. of subgroups which are not normal

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. Let $t$ be the no. of subgroups of $G$ which are not normal. Prove that $t\neq 1$.

My Work:

Case 1: $G$ is abelian. Then all subgroups are normal. Hence, $t=0$

Case 2: $G$ is non abelian. Assume $t=1$. Then there is a subgroup $H$ which is not normal in $G$. Then if there is another subgroup $K$ such that $K\neq H,G,\{0\}$ then $K\triangleleft G$. Then I was going to get a contradiction using 2nd isomorphism theorem. But how can I prove the existence of such $K$? I am stuck now. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if there is only a single subgroup $H$ not being normal, then any conjugate $H^{g}$ must also be not normal. Hence $H=H^{g}$ ...

Comment: By conjugate do you mean $gHg^{-1}$?

Comment: Yes indeed! What conclusion gives you this?

Comment: You may also want to look inside my paper http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01188515#page-1